# Content Management System which integrates with mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, database-management

I have a mysql database which contains several tables. At the moment i'm using phpmyadmin to add entries to the database but i'm looking for a more convenient way of updating the database.

Are there any content management systems which integrate with a mysql database?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Edit:

I forgot to mention that this isn't for a website, it's used as data storage for android and iphone apps.

Comment: Are you looking for a CMS or something to manage your database?  I use SQLyog for managing my databases, and am very happy with it.  http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list

Comment: I'm just looking for something to manage the database which has a more user-friendly interface than phpmyadmin, as I need users to be able to login and edit information in the database without knowledge required for the likes of phpmyadmin

Comment: so you are actually looking for a CMS then?  Please make up your mind.  Are you looking for something to do administrative tasks for your your database, or are these "users" actually users of your program that need a web-based interface to do things with your custom database?  Who are the "users"... you or others?

Comment: I had a look at sqlyog and it would be an overkill, I wouldn't need all those features. I'm just looking for something that allows the average user to login and add/create/delete an entry in the database. Users being administrators of the database

Comment: A content management system would be ideal but I can't find one which does not have a front end website attached to it. I just need a content management system that manages the database, so wordpress and joomla obviously are not ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find a "CMS" for a custom database.  If you have a custom database, you will need to make your own custom front-end for managing it.

You can always link tables in MS Access to your MySQL database, but this has a few problems.  It is generally best if you just make a web front end to meet your needs.